# Mongodb C# - Registering class maps with generics works, where using types fails

Tags: c#, mongodb, serialization, reflection

I have a collection of objects, and each object has a property, EventData, that is many different types. These types all inherit from an `IEventData` interface.

For example:

```
{ _id: '...', EventData: { _t: 'TypeA', ... } }
{ _id: '...', EventData: { _t: 'TypeB', ... } }
```

I'm currently facing an issue with the MongoDB C# driver when trying to register class maps.
When using the generic version to register the class map, the EventData object is correctly serialised with all properties and the type discriminator:

```
BsonClassMap.RegisterClassMap<TypeA>();
// Full event data is written to collection
// { _id: '...', EventData: { _t: 'TypeA', InterfaceProperty: '...', ClassProperty: '...' } }
```

This works fine, however I have a large amount of different event types, and want to try and use some reflection to help automate this. When trying to use the non-generic version of the RegisterClassMap whilst iterating over all types that implement the IEventData interface, only the interface members are serialised:

```
var types = AppDomain.CurrentDomain.GetAssemblies()
.SelectMany(i => i.GetTypes())
.Where(t => typeof(IEventData).IsAssignableFrom(t));

foreach (var type in types)
{
    // If it's an interface, skip as we can't register those
    if (type.IsInterface)
        continue;
        
    if (!BsonClassMap.IsClassMapRegistered(type))
       BsonClassMap.RegisterClassMap(new BsonClassMap(type));
        
 }

// Only the interface properties are written to collection
// { _id: '...', EventData: { _t: 'TypeA', InterfaceProperty: '...' } }
```

Is there some property or something I'm missing to set when using the non-generic type to register the class maps that allow the full type to stored in the collection?

Thanks
Justin

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The difference between the two variants is that in case of `RegisterClassMap<T>()` a call to [`AutoMap`](https://github.com/mongodb/mongo-csharp-driver/blob/089a54da5d10266613f6402b2091c31fe845dac8/src/MongoDB.Bson/Serialization/BsonClassMap.cs#L378) is included. In order to harmonize your reflection based approach with the call of the generic version, you can add the call to `AutoMap`:

```
var cm = new BsonClassMap(type);
cm.AutoMap();
BsonClassMap.RegisterClassMap(cm);
```